# Authenticate with Firebase Using Email Link in Android: UNAUTHORIZED_DOMAIN error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

From [quickstart-android](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android) samples projects I'm trying the Firebase Auth Quickstart sample targeting the Passwordless method with these versions:

```
// Firebase Authentication
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'

// Google Sign In SDK (only required for Google Sign In)
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

// Firebase UI
// Used in FirebaseUIActivity.
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'
```

I've followed the setup as documented in the project [README](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth#passwordless-setup) but I get the following error (Logcat):

```
06-25 10:51:31.603 3657-3657/com.google.firebase.quickstart.auth W/PasswordlessSignIn: Could not send link
    com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ UNAUTHORIZED_DOMAIN:Domain not whitelisted by project ]
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzce.zzb(Unknown Source:55)
```

The `Firebase->Authentication->Authorized domain` table contains `<my-project-name>.firebaseapp.com` as authorized domain.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy domain from Dynamic Link:

[image]

2. Go to Authentication in SignIn-Methods:

[image]

3. Add your domain:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Now you need to go  `Authentication->Settings->Authorized domains`. And add the domain of your dynamic link. It must start with `www`, e.g: [www.example.page.link](http://www.example.page.link)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

First make sure that you already add domain **'yourdomain.com'** to Authentication menu in Firebase at Authorized domains. If you already have your domain declared there, assuming that you are using:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
}
```

Try to update to the latest version like:

```
    // Firebase Authentication
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

// Google Sign In SDK (only required for Google Sign In)
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

// Firebase UI
// Used in FirebaseUIActivity.
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.1'
```

Also make sure that you are using:

```
implementation "com.android.support:design:27.1.1"
implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1"
```

Also if you are using other firebase libraries check that everything is updated based [on this link](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android):

```
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
```

Comment: Many Thanks @Paraskevas: I missed to setup the Dynamic Links. Afterwards I've tested with your suggested versions but it still does not work. I suspect that my issue is related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50175974/firebase-andorid-email-link-authentication-intent-filter-not-working)

Comment: @attdona i suggest you add implementation of all firebase libraries and check if it it is work, i had similar problem in the past and because i dont know why my project doesnt work i add all libraries and it works with no reason..

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works using this method:

```
ActionCodeSettings settings = ActionCodeSettings
  .newBuilder()
  .setUrl("https://auth.example.com/emailSignInLink")
```

Set Authorized domains in the console too: `auth.example.com`